# how does the Character pointer treats MSB bit of each byte?

Tags: c, pointers

for the following code:

```
void main()
{
   int i;
   float a=5.2;
   char *ptr;
   ptr=(char *)&a;
   for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
      printf("%d ",*ptr++);
}
```

i m getting o/p as 102 102 -90 64..why?how does the Character pointer treats MSB bit of each byte?

Comment: I've noticed your code is consistently unformatted. Please take the time to learn how to use the formatting tools so that someone doesn't have to fix each question you ask.

Comment: Use `unsigned char*` if you don't like negative values.

Comment: If your textbook told you to use `void main()`, get a better textbook. `int main(void)` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Whether char is signed or unsigned is implementation defined. Clearly the char data type in your system is signed. So the MSB is the sign bit.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, apparently it treats the most significant bit as a sign bit, in other words, in your implementation `char` is a signed integer type, with two's complement representation, incidentally.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the `5.2` floating point value into binary format you get:

```
5.2 = 01000000 (=64) 10100110 (=166) 01100110 (=102) 01100110 (= 102)
```

If you take the 3rd byte (`166`) and convert it into a `signed char` value (within `[-128, 127]`) then you obtain `-90`.

Compile your program with `-funsigned-char` to obtain `102 102 166 64` as output.

Answer (score 0):

In your case , the `char` is using signed bit representation. As far as the values are concerned , they depend on the [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the system you are working on.